# Skill's app ID: Secure to include in public repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, github, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa Skill with [Skill Kit SDK](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs), and now I prepare to publish my Skill's repository on Github. During development I included my Skill's app ID in the according `index.js` file and diligently committed my work with my local git.

Is there a risk involved in publishing my Skill's repository with my actual app ID? I could imagine that a malicious party might use the app ID (together with the ARN of my Skill's Lambda function) to send lots of requests and thus incur costs on AWS, but maybe there are other risks.

It seems to be good practice not to include the app ID in the public repository, since [no](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-quiz-game/blob/master/src/index.js) [example](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-highlowgame/blob/master/src/index.js) [Skill](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-trivia/blob/master/src/index.js) of the [official Amazon Alexa organization](https://github.com/alexa) has their respective app ID included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly, people put these keys/secrets in as an environmental variable and in the code write `process.env.SKILL_KIT_KEY` to retrieve it.

I would *strongly* recommend, if you make the switch, to deactivate the key you've used and that lives in plain-text in the repo's history and obtain a new one.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I did, and it works nicely. One deviation from you approach is that I couldn't change the ID of an existing Skill, so I cloned it and deleted the Skill with the published ID.

Comment: This answer would be significantly better if it answered the question.  You discuss how to hide the ID, but never discuss whether hiding is necessary or the security implications of having it public

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to include a configuration file that contains all login or password information. You might name this file config.js. Then exclude this file from being checked into Git by listing it in the .gitignore file.

To help others to recreate this file with their own information, provide a well commented template version of this file in the project. Append "Template" to the name (eg. config_template.js) with instructions to rename it to config.js after editing it to include all their own information.